# How do I check whether a given directory is empty with Ansible?

Tags: ansible, yaml

I am trying to implement a role that checks whether a given directory is empty before proceeding with the rest of the playbook.

I have tried this code but I am getting an error and I am not sure about the correct implementation.

```
- name: Check if d folder is empty before proceeding
  find:
   paths: c/d/
   patterns: "*.*"
   register: filesFound

- fail:
     msg: The d folder is not empty. 
  when: filesFound.matched > 0

- debug:
    msg: "The d folder is empty. Proceeding."
```

This is the error that I am getting:

```
fatal FAILED! =>
{"changed": false,
"module_stderr": "Exception calling \"Create\" with \"1\" argument(s):
\"At line:4 char:21
def _ansiballz_main():
An expression was expected after '('.
At line:12 char:27
except (AttributeError, OSError):
Missing argument in parameter list.
At line:14 char:7
if scriptdir is not None:
Missing '(' after 'if' in if statement.
At line:21 char:7
if sys.version_info < (3,):
Missing '(' after 'if' in if statement.
At line:21 char:30
if sys.version_info < (3,):
Missing expression after ','.
At line:21 char:25
if sys.version_info < (3,):
The '<' operator is reserved for future use.
At line:23 char:32
MOD_DESC = ('.py', 'U', imp.PY_SOURCE)
Missing expression after ','.
At line:23 char:33
MOD_DESC = ('.py', 'U', imp.PY_SOURCE)                                 Unexpected token 'imp.PY_SOURCE' in expression or statement.
At line:23 char:32
MOD_DESC = ('.py', 'U', imp.PY_SOURCE)
Missing closing ')' in expression.
At line:23 char:46
MOD_DESC = ('.py', 'U', imp.PY_SOURCE)
Unexpected token ')' in expression or statement.
Not all parse errors were reported.  Correct the reported errors and try again.\"
At line:6 char:1
$exec_wrapper = [ScriptBlock]::Create($split_parts[0])
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException\r\n    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParseException\r\n \r\nThe expression after '&' in a pipeline element produced an object that was not valid. It must result in a command
name, a script block, or a CommandInfo object.
At line:7 char:2
&$exec_wrapper
~~~~~~~~~~~~~\
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : BadExpression
", "module_stdout": "", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE
See stdout/stderr for the exact error", "rc": 1}
```

Comment: In your code there is an  indentation error. Register should be at the same level as find. Also the error you posted doesn't seem to be complete

Comment: @HermanTheGermanHesse Thank you, I have updated the error with the full error. I have tried both of your suggestions and am still getting the same error

Comment: Are you by any chance trying to run this on Windows?

Answer (score 22):

You are on the right way, but as [@HermanTheGermanHesse](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6196947/hermanthegermanhesse) mentioned, there is an idention error, try this:

```
- name: Check if d folder is empty before proceeding
  find:
    paths: 'c/d/'
  register: filesFound

- fail:
     msg: 'The d folder is not empty.'
  when: filesFound.matched > 0

- debug:
    msg: 'The d folder is empty. Proceeding.'
```

Comment: this will **not** work if there aren't normal files in the directory (e.g. there are only subdirectories, and/or only dotfiles); you need to add `file_type: any` and `hidden: yes` to form a full query as to whether or not the directory is empty.

Comment: You can optimise the answer using failed_when, i.e. `failed_when: filesFound.matched > 0`

Answer (score 4):

You could use the [shell module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/shell_module.html#shell-module).

```
- name: Register contents of /a/b/c
  shell: ls -lA # Thank you Life5ign
  args:
    chdir: /a/b/c
  register: contents

- name: do stuff when not empty
  debug:
    msg: "There are elements inside!"
  when: contents["stdout_lines"] | length > 0 # Thank you Life5ign
```

Comment: you can make the conditional zero-based by using `ls -lA` "almost all", which omits `.` and `..`, which represent the "2" in your comparison, and change it to 0.  Also, you should use `ansible.bulitin.command` instead of `shell` unless you need shell metacharacters, which you don't in this example.

Comment: @Life5ign good catch with `-lA`!
Could you please point me to the docs regarding the differences (underlying and in-use) of the shell and the command modules?

Comment: Yes, the documentation for the `command` module, below the input parameters, points this out: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/command_module.html#ansible-collections-ansible-builtin-command-module and there is more commentary in the `shell` module doc, which is linked to

Comment: This method is also much faster than the `find` method above, especially and mainly if there are many files in the directory, and as such, even though ansible recommends using specially purposed modules instead of command/shell much of the time, is preferable in my use case.

Comment: The "long" format of `ls -lA` returns at least one line (`total ...`), so either use `ls -A` (short format) or change the `length > 0` to `length > 1`

Answer (score -2):

Solution inspired by [Jeremy Canfield](http://www.freekb.net/Article?id=2751) which checks if a directory contains files:

```
- name: Check if d folder is empty before proceeding
  stat:
    path: c/d/*
  register: filesFound

- fail:
     msg: The d folder is not empty. 
  when: filesFound.stat.exists == true

- debug:
    msg: The d folder is empty. Proceeding.
  when: filesFound.stat.exists == false
```

Comment: This doesn't work; `stat` doesn't accept globs in its "path" parameter, from my tests